# Vainfo error message with Intel Elkhart lake platform

Tags: drivers, vaapi

Chipset is Intel Elkhart lake
Ubuntu OS version : 20.04 desktop amd64-intel-iot.iso
Kernel version : 5.13.0.1017-intel

I had done sudo apt-get update / apt upgrade to make sure my OS base is up to date.
Searching some data about vainfo and vaapi of Intel which supported by iHD driver for Elkhart lake already.
Does anyone fix this issue already or any hints for sharing ?

below is the output:

```
ibva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Comment: I'd check your system is up-to-date, as 5.13 kernel is from 21.10 & isn't *supported* anymore on *focal* or 20.04; it's been replaced by 5.15 for users using HWE.  You do mention `apt upgrade` but if you read the manual for it, there are cases where that won't upgrade packages which is why `apt full-upgrade` exists.  A fully-upgraded system in your case would be using `linux-image-5.15.0-1010-intel-iotg` not what you pasted.

Comment: I try atp full-upgarde , but get below

<pre>sudo apt full-upgrade</pre>
<pre>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use &apos;sudo apt autoremove&apos; to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
</pre>
<pre>uname -r
5.13.0-1017-intel
</pre>